# How to build a conditional cells merging in excel 2010?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of raw data in 3 languages, when most of it is in `.xlsx`.
You can think about the data as table contains 3 columns and a lot of rows(millions).

I want to build a macro which implement this:

checks if the cell on your adjacent cells is empty, merge yourself to the above cell.

```
if (the cell on your left is empty):
     merge yourself to the above cell;
```

I have no knowledge in VB, but I want to implement it by myself, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to answer without more information but this outlines some of the issues.

You need somewhere to store the row and column of the cell of interest:

```
Dim ColCrnt As Long
Dim RowCrnt As Long
```

If you want to run down a column, you could write something like:

```
ColCrnt = 5     ' 5 represents column "E".  Columns are numbered from 1.

For RowCrnt = 1 to 1000
  'Update code.
Next
```

If you want to move the cursor around and then call the macro, you could write something like:

```
ColCrnt = ActiveCell.Column
RowCrnt = ActiveCell.Row
' Update Code.
```

Assuming the update code is to operate on the active worksheet, it will be something like:

```
If Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt - 1).Value = "" Then
  Cells(RowCrnt-1, ColCrnt).Value = _
          Cells(RowCrnt-1, ColCrnt).Value & Cells(RowCrnt-1, ColCrnt).Value    
  Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value = ""
End If
```

`Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value` is the value of the current cell.  Subtracting 1 from RowCrnt, references the cell above.  Subtracting 1 from ColCrnt, references the cell to the left.

`Cells(RowCrnt-1, ColCrnt).Value = Cells(RowCrnt-1, ColCrnt).Value & Cells(RowCrnt-1, ColCrnt).Value` concatenates the value of the current cell to the end of the cell above.

`Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value = ""` clears the current cell.

So:

```
       |    E    |
       |---------|
       | The     |
       | cat     |
```

becomes:

```
       |    E    |
       |---------|
       | Thecat  |
       |         |
```

If you want a space between "The" and "cat":

```
  Cells(RowCrnt-1, ColCrnt).Value = _
       Cells(RowCrnt-1, ColCrnt).Value & " " & Cells(RowCrnt-1, ColCrnt).Value
```

If you want "cat" on a new line::

```
  Cells(RowCrnt-1, ColCrnt).Value = _
      Cells(RowCrnt-1, ColCrnt).Value & vblf & Cells(RowCrnt-1, ColCrnt).Value
```

Note: a cell can take a very long string but only the beginning will be visible.

Hope this gets you started.